# Issue with Rails Active Record query with JSON parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I have a `Notification` model with a `notification_objects` parameter.  `Notification.first.notification_objects` returns an array of hashes.  I've created a `@notification_objects` variable that holds the an array of hashes with the same key/value pairs (except with symbols instead of strings for keys).  How can I find this first `Notification` using `Notification.where()`?  Stringifying the keys in @notification_objects did not work.  I'm using Postgres 9.4 and Rails 4.2.

```
[18] pry(main)> Notification.first.notification_objects
=> [{"class_name"=>"Ad", "ar_object_id"=>1}]

[19] pry(main)> @notification_objects
=> [{:class_name=>"Ad", :ar_object_id=>1}]


# both as_json and to_json do not work here:
[20] pry(main)> Notification.where(notification_objects: @notification_objects.as_json)
=> []

[21] pry(main)> @notification_objects.as_json
=> [{"class_name"=>"Ad", "ar_object_id"=>1}]

[22] pry(main)> Notification.first.notification_objects.as_json == @notification_objects.as_json
=> true
```

Comment: Which DB are you using? `notification_object` is a String type in db?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `.to_json` instead of `.as_json`

```
Notification.where(notification_objects: @notification_objects.to_json)
```

`.to_json` returns a JSON string representing the model.

references: 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json